# How can I get data in List using name in Python language?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In C language, for example,

```
typedef struct People_S
{
    int age;
    int grade;
}People;

People tmp[10] = {0};
```

Then I can use `tmp[0].grade` to access the data.

In Python, however, I have no ideal how to do it. If using list `tmp = [[10,60],[11,50]]`, i can get the `grade` by `tmp[0][1]`. But too much magic number is not good for reading.

Thanks for your helf!

Comment: See data classes of python 3.7

Comment: Python has classes. `class Person:\n def __init__(self, age, grade):self.age,self.grade = age,grade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with using iteration on a list, you could as well use dictionaries if you do not like full fledged classes:

```
dictList = []
for i in range(5):
    dictList.append({"age":i+10,"grade": i//3})

print(dictList)
print( dictList[2]["grade"], dictList[2]["age"] )

for e in dictList:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
[{'grade': 0, 'age': 10}, {'grade': 0, 'age': 11}, {'grade': 0, 'age': 12}, 
 {'grade': 1, 'age': 13}, {'grade': 1, 'age': 14}]

(0, 12)

{'age': 10, 'grade': 0}
{'age': 11, 'grade': 0}
{'age': 12, 'grade': 0}
{'age': 13, 'grade': 1}
{'age': 14, 'grade': 1}
```

Or the previously mentioned classes (see [PyTut: A first look at classes](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)):

```
class People:
    def __init__(self,age,grade):
        self.age=age
        self.grade=grade

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Age {self.age} Grade {self.grade}"

classList = []
for i in range(5):
    classList.append( People(i+10,i//3))

print(*classList,sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Age 10 Grade 0
Age 11 Grade 0
Age 12 Grade 0
Age 13 Grade 1
Age 14 Grade 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option besides classes or dictionaries is `namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> People = namedtuple('People','age grade')
>>> People(10,60)
People(age=10, grade=60)
>>> p = People(10,60)
>>> p.age
10
>>> p.grade
60
```

A way to populate a `People` list:

```
>>> tmp = [[10,60],[11,50]]
>>> p = [People(age,grade) for age,grade in tmp]
>>> p
[People(age=10, grade=60), People(age=11, grade=50)]
```

Comment: I like namedtuples: easy to set up, easy to use, very clear.  And if your program grows in complexity you may be glad that converting a namedtuple to a class is also pretty easy.

Comment: didn't know about named tuples - nice feature.

Comment: Note: `namedtuple`s *are* classes, they're just ones that Python generates for you (that subclass `tuple` to provide immutability guarantees and interoperability). Also note that as of 3.5, there is [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), a replacement for `collections.namedtuple` which allows for safe typing, and added more flexibility as well in 3.6, which in turn paved the way for 3.7's [`dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which provides maximally flexible class generation capabilities.